# How to set an intent so that I can send a data to the second activity and from there to the third activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I get input from user in first activity and send that to a second activity. From the second activity, using the user input, I fetch data from the db and  want to send that data to a third activity. How do I give the intent from the second activity to the third activity?

Comment: Exactly same how did you done from first activity to second activity.. Or you mean some custom data?

Comment: If the data is in the database you can have the third activity take it from there instead of passing it an intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are starting each activity using an Intent in which case you could pass data as an extra.

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("user_input_key", "user_input");
startActivity(i);
```

In the second activity onCreate

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String userInput = extras.getString("user_input_key");
    //Once activity starts use this string to get data from DB and put/get extra in the same way
}
```

You shouldn't be passing the intent between activities. Identify exactly what you want to pass between activities and put that data in the intent as an extra and retrieve that data in the new Activity onCreate.

Comment: Actually I am not passing intent between activities after getting the data from second activity I want to pass that to third activity but if I create a new intent it is not working

Comment: I would check how you are creating and calling the intent in the second activity, as well as how you are retrieving the extra in your third activity. Without your code I can only speculate as to what could be happening.